# WPF C# ViewModel with Computed Properties and Dependency Tracking. Analog of Knockut JS

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight, mvvm

Is there any library that implements MVVM's ViewModel in a fashion of Knockout JS.

So, it should support [Computed Properties](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) with automatic [Dependency Tracking](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html).

I didn't finde something seamless for notifications and validations together (how I know it in Knockout JS ).

Or, please, give me an advice how to do this stuff nowadays.

I had my own codebase for that. It even supported dependency tracking for Func-validators (that I like too).
All this was a long ago and now it uncompilable.

---

Some examples for what I meant.

```
public partial class MyViewModel : ValidatableViewModel

// Some property with the validator.

    public Double? LoanAmount
    {
        get { return _innerDataObject.LoanAmount; }
        set
        {
            _innerDataObject.LoanAmount = value;

            // Validators with dependency tracking.
            PropertyChangedInSetter(new ValidatableContext("LoanAmount")
                {
                    FuncValidators = new List<Func<ValidationResult>>
                        {
                            () =>
                            {
                                if (LoanParametersEnabled == false)
                                    return null;

                                if (LoanParametersUnrequired
                                    && LoanAmount.HasValue == false)
                                    return null;

                                if (LoanAmount.HasValue == false)
                                    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessages.RequiredValue);

                                // ... 
                            }
                        },

                }
            );
        }
    }
```

// Some compluted property.

```
    public Double? LimitLoanProductCalculated
    {
        get
        {
            // dependency tracking for a computed property.
            var res = GetComputedResult(() => GetSomeThingsForUi(
                LimitLoanProductMax,
                CardVariantOrNull,
                LimitGlobalCalculated
                ));

            return res;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As some idea http://www.codemag.com/article/0907101 and http://updatecontrols.net/cs/

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Ah, I wish I knew. This was downvoted more than once only in first day. Hope those were guys who search a quick reputation and this is not my fault. But all can be)) Now I'm really scared to ask any questions on StackOverflow to prevent destroy of my small reputation, haha

Comment: Even Cameron below was downvoted. That makes me sad because he let me know something new.

Comment: Didn't know about Fody either, interesting project. I might integrate Moldinium with it at some point.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote [Moldinium](https://github.com/jtheisen/moldinium), which does Knockout-style dependency tracking for .NET.

From the readme:

Moldinium lets you define classes like this:

```
public abstract class Course : IModel
{
    public abstract String Name { get; set; }

    public abstract Room Location { get; set; }

    public virtual String Description
        => $"course {Name} in room {Location.Name}";
}

public abstract class Room : IModel
{
    public abstract String Name { get; set; }
}
```

And you get the following without any additional code:

- An implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` for all properties declared abstract or virtual.
- The property `Course.Description` will automatically update on a change to either `Course.Location` or `Course.Location.Name`.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/fody/propertychanged) for years now. It works with automatic properties as well as calculated properties.

Comment: Hmm. I only knew about PostSharp before. What if I need a dependency tracking from validators? How I see I have to write my own Fody plugin for that and this would be really messy and costly for a team. Or I have missed some thing? Anyway thank you! Never heard before.

Comment: Hah! _"I've used ... for years"_, now I see. You're [first contributor for Fody](https://github.com/orgs/Fody/people). It's not my way, absolutely)) System coder never digging so deep where App developer dug. It is joke, of course, Cameron.

Comment: @IlyaTretyakovit3xl :) Fody is like PostSharp, it's a post-compile system. I have written other plugins but PropertyChanged was written by Simon Cropp.